# Can't get MySQL.connector to work with Scrapy in Python

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am having problems exporting scraped data using Scrapy to a local MySQL database.

Anyway, I attempted to make a web crawler using Scrapy, and so far it does in fact scrape the needed data from the desired website, though I cannot get it to export the data to a local MySQL database. I have been reading the documentation for Mysql connector, but their example confuses me a bit (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html). I also searched on Google, hoping that I could find a solution, but all the results I find use MySQLdb, and I would like to use the MySQL connector.

**Here is my code in the pipelines.py**

```
from scrapy.extensions import DropItem
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pwd', host='localhost', database='ftdb2')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

TABLES = {}

TABLES['fttable2'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE 'fttable2' ("
    "  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  'nr' varchar(100),"
    "  'titel' varchar(9999),"
    "  'forslagsstiller' varchar(999),"
    "  'ministeromraade' varchar(100),"
    "  'udvalg' varchar(100),"
    "  'status' varchar(100),"
    "  'samling' varchar(100),"
    "  PRIMARY KEY ('id')"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")

add = ("INSERT INTO fttable2 " "(nr) " "VALUES (item['nr'])")
cursor.execute(add)
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()

class tutorial2Pipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

When I go to the terminal -> mysql -> and write: `describe fttable2;`, I can see that it hasn't even created the table (I made sure to grant the user full privileges).

**Here is the spider.py code** (built upon the one from the Scrapy tutorial):

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector 
from tutorial2.items import FTItem

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["ft.dk"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.ft.dk/Dokumenter/Vis_efter_type/Beslutningsforslag.aspx?session=&caseStatus=-1&ministerArea=-1&committee=&proposedBy=1&startDate=20110915&endDate=20140421&dateRelatedActivity=100242%2f200049&sortColumn=&sortOrder=&startRecord=&totalNumberOfRecords=&numberOfRecords=999&pageNr=#dok"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = FTItem()
        # Extract title
        item['nr'] = sel.xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

I am not really sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: You don't execute `CREATE TABLE ...` in your code so you don't have table in database.

Comment: thank you for your reply. This partially helped me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Scrapy will call enabled pipeline functions, but the piece of your mysql code are not written within the scope of any pipeline functions.

Comment: @Payeli I disagree with your comment and your -1. I think he should put his piece of mysql codes (from creating cnx mysql connector to cnx.close()) into a pipeline function (eg. tutorial2Pipeline) .

Comment: thanks sammyfung. I changed the code to have it in the pipeline and it works great. now I only have problems with the sql command INSERT INTO, but I will post a separate one that addresses this as the code has changed quite a bit now. thanks for the help.